# Use a dataframe as lookup for another dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lookup-tables

I’ve two dataframes `df_1` and `df_2`

`df_1` is my master dataframe and `df_2` is a lookup dataframe.

I want to test if the value in `df_1[‘col_c1’]` contains any of the the values from `df_2[‘col_a2’]`.
If this is true (can be multiple matches !);

- add the value(s) from `df_2[‘col_b2’]` to `df_1[‘col_d1’]`
- add the value(s) from `df_2[‘col_c2’]` to `df_1[‘col_e1’]`

How can i achieve this?
I’ve really no idea and therefore I can’t share any code for this.

Sample `df_1`

```
col_a1 | col_b1 | col_c1         | col_d1 | col_e1
----------------------------------------------------
1_001  | aaaaaa | bbbbccccdddd   |        | 
1_002  | zzzzz  | ggggjjjjjkkkkk |        | 
1_003  | pppp   | qqqqffffgggg   |        | 
1_004  | sss    | wwwcccyyy      |        |
1_005  | eeeeee | eecccffffll    |        |
1_006  | tttt   | hhggeeuuuuu    |        |
```

Sample `df_2`

```
col_a2 | col_b2 | col_c2
------------------------------
ccc    | 2_001  | some_data_c
jjj    | 2_002  | some_data_j
fff    | 2_003  | some_data_f
```

Desired output `df_1`

```
col_a1 | col_b1 | col_c1         | col_d1       | col_e1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1_001  | aaaaaa | bbbbccccdddd   | 2_001        | some_data_c
1_002  | zzzzz  | ggggjjjjjkkkkk | 2_002        | some_data_j
1_003  | pppp   | qqqqffffgggg   | 2_003        | some_data_f
1_004  | sss    | wwwcccyyy      | 2_001        | some_data_c
1_005  | eeeeee | eecccffffll    | 2_001;2_003  | some_data_c; some_data_f
1_006  | tttt   | hhggeeuuuuu    |              |
```

df_1 has approx 45.000 rows and df_2 approx. 16.000 rows. (Also added a non matching row)

I've been struggling with this for hours, but I really have no idea.
I don't think merging is an option because there's no exact match.
Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#exctract values by df_2["col_a2"] to new column
s = (df_1['col_c1'].str.extractall(f'({"|".join(df_2["col_a2"])})')[0].rename('new')
                   .reset_index(level=1, drop=True))

#repeat rows with duplicated match
df_1 = df_1.join(s)
#add new columns by map
df_1['col_d1'] = df_1['new'].map(df_2.set_index('col_a2')['col_b2'])
df_1['col_e1'] = df_1['new'].map(df_2.set_index('col_a2')['col_c2'])
#aggregate join
cols = df_1.columns.difference(['new','col_d1','col_e1']).tolist()
df = df_1.drop('new', axis=1).groupby(cols).agg(','.join).reset_index()

print (df)
  col_a1  col_b1          col_c1       col_d1                   col_e1
0  1_001  aaaaaa    bbbbccccdddd        2_001              some_data_c
1  1_002   zzzzz  ggggjjjjjkkkkk        2_002              some_data_j
2  1_003    pppp    qqqqffffgggg        2_003              some_data_f
3  1_004     sss       wwwcccyyy        2_001              some_data_c
4  1_005  eeeeee     eecccffffll  2_001,2_003  some_data_c,some_data_f
```

Comment: This gives me an error: `pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`

Comment: It's this line: `df_1['col_d1'] = df_1['new'].map(df_2.set_index('col_a2')['col_b2'])` and probably also the next one.

Comment: @JohnDoe - Ok, so please try `df_2.set_index('col_a2')['col_b2']` change to `df_2.groupby('col_a2')['col_b2'].apply(','.join)`

Comment: No errors anymore but the output is not as desired. It's not filling in `col_d1` and `col_e1`. it's only adding a colum `0` with column names instead of values. `col_d1` and `col_e1` don't exist anymore.

Comment: Can you please help me out? Your code is much faster than the solution from `Iamklaus` and I think we are close to the desired solution.

Comment: @John Doe Are real data confidental? If not, is possible sent it to my email from my profile? Because seems some data related problem, because my solution not working.

Comment: I've this issue also with the data provided in my question.   
`0 1_001 aaaaaa bbbbccccdddd col_a1,col_b1,col_c1,col_d1,col_e1`   
I've created two xlsx files (`df_1.xlsx` and `df_2.xlsx`) and then read the data in `df_1` and `df_2`.   
They both look fine. I've this issue with your original code and also after changing `df_2.set_index('col_a2')['col_b2']` to `df_2.groupby('col_a2')['col_b2'].apply(','.join)`

Comment: @JohnDoe - Problem are missing values, can you check `df = df_1.drop('new', axis=1).fillna('Na').groupby(cols).agg(','.join).reset_index().replace('Na', np.nan)`

Comment: Thanks again. This works like a charm in just over 2 minutes !!

Answer (score 1):

this will solve it

```
df['col_d1'] = df.apply(lambda x: ','.join([df2['col_b2'][i] for i in range(len(df2)) if df2['col_a2'][i] in x.col_c1]), axis=1)

df['col_e1'] = df.apply(lambda x: ','.join([df2['col_c2'][i] for i in range(len(df2)) if df2['col_a2'][i] in x.col_c1]), axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
    col_a1    col_b1            col_c1             col_d1  \
0  1_001     aaaaaa    bbbbccccdddd               2_001     
1  1_002     zzzzz     ggggjjjjjkkkkk             2_002     
2  1_003     pppp      qqqqffffgggg               2_003     
3  1_004     sss       wwwcccyyy                  2_001     
4  1_005     eeeeee    eecccffffll       2_001  , 2_003     

                      col_e1  
0                some_data_c  
1                some_data_j  
2                some_data_f  
3                some_data_c  
4   some_data_c; some_data_f
```

Comment: This give me the desired output but it's very slow. Is it possible to do it in one iteration for example. by concatenating  `col_b2` and `col_c2`and splitting it afterwards?